# Foreign Key Constraint Problem

Tags: mysql

The tables in question are:

**enquiry**

- id
- accepted_quote_id

**supplier_enquiry**

- id
- enquiry_id

**quote**

- id
- enquiry_id
- supplier_enquiry_id

The constraints are as follows:

- CONSTRAINT `supplier_enquiry_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`enquiry_id`) REFERENCES `enquiry` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
- CONSTRAINT `quote_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`supplier_enquiry_id`) REFERENCES `supplier_enquiry` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
- CONSTRAINT `enquiry_ibfk_9` FOREIGN KEY (`accepted_quote_id`) REFERENCES `quote` (`id`)

So the way I expect this to work is:

1. If you delete an 'enquiry' it deletes the child 'supplier_enquiry' records
2. If you delete a 'supplier_enquiry' it deletes the child 'quote' records
3. You cannnot delete a 'quote' if an 'enquiry' references that quote's ID

The problem I'm having is when deleting an 'enquiry' record. Because it needs to delete the child records first, i.e. 'supplier_enquiry' and 'quote', if 'accepted_quote_id' references a 'quote' then the 'enquiry' can't be deleted.

Any idea how I can overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get rid of the circular reference by making the two other tables dependant on enquiry.

So:

quote.enquiry_id references enquiry.id

And:

supplier_enquiry.enquiry_id references enquiry.id

EDIT: That might be unclear.  I'm suggesting making a new constraint on the quote table that references enquiry_id to enquiry.id, then removing enquiry_ibfk_9

Answer (score 0):

Update the reference to NULL before deleting.